# What is the rationale behind this method of computing the w-component from MD5 mesh files?

Tags: quaternion

In tutorials regarding the MD5Mesh format, like [this one](http://tfc.duke.free.fr/coding/md5-specs-en.html), we often see code like

```
float t = 1.0f - (q.x * q.x) - (q.y * q.y) - (q.z * q.z);

if (t < 0.0f) {
   q.w = 0.0f;
} else {
   q.w = -sqrt (t);
}
```

for computing the w-component of a unit quaternion given `x, y, z`.
Why do we obtain w in this manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MD5 file format assumes unit quaternions, which are of norm one. The norm of some quaternion `q` is:

```
|q| = sqrt((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z) + (w * w))
```

You can rearrange this equation in terms of `w` by squaring both sides and then subtracting the terms containing `x`, `y` and `z` to yield:

```
(w*w) = (|q|*|q|) - (x*x) - (y*y) - (z*z)
```

Since the quaternion is assumed to be of norm 1, the `|q|*|q|` term is thus 1, and that's how you arrive at the initialization of `t` in your code snippet. Taking the square root of `t` yields the value of the final component, the sign of which is chosen as an orientation convention.

Comment: Working the problem by hand, I arrived at `w = ± sqrt(1 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2)`, but I am shaky on the if-statement logic. Does `t < 0` occur often in practice? What I am trying to figure out is if we are mitigating the effects of bad input by setting `w` to a reasonable value of 0 (I am new to quaternions, so forgive my greenness).

Comment: @pcapp, you could add logging to that branch, but I think it's less about mitigating bad input and more about not getting `NaN` when rounding causes t to be something like `-1E-9`.